# How to find duplicate values in an array without using array_count_values

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to find duplicated values/string in an array using `for` loop

```
    <?php
    $b=array('a','b','c','a','b');
    $c=count($b);
    $d=array();

    for($i=0;$i<=($c-1);$i++)
    {
        for($j=1;$j<=($c-1);$j++)
        {       

            if($b[$i]!=$b[$j])
            {       
             $flag=1;   
            }

        }

        if($flag==1)
        {
        $d[$i]=$b[$i];
        }

    }   

    print_R($d);
    ?>
```

where is my mistake? I have used array $d to display non duplicate values.....

**NOTE:** I need to try this **only** with `for` loop - I know how to do it using array functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reverse your test, because there are almost always values, which are different from the one you're testing. And you must reset your `$flag` before the inner loop, otherwise it will always be true.

When you want to find unique values, you can just test against `$d` only. If the value is already in `$d`, skip it.

```
$c1 = count($b);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c1; $i++) {
    $dup = 0;
    $c2 = count($d);
    for ($j = 0; $j < $c2; $j++) {
        if ($b[$i] == $d[$j])
            $dup = 1;
    }

    if (!$dup)
        $d[] = $b[$i];
}

print_r($d);
```

If you want to find values, which don't have duplicates instead

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    $dup = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < $c; $j++) {
        if ($i != $j && $b[$i] == $b[$j])
            $dup = 1;
    }

    if (!$dup)
        $d[] = $b[$i];
}
```

Comment: hello olaf,using array functions i know to do it.... iam just trying with for loop....

Comment: @user1659450 Please see modified answer.

Comment: thanks for your response olaf, foreach is fine ... but just curious to know is there a way to find display unique value through 'for loop itself'?

Comment: @user1659450 Yes, of course. I just edited the first example to work with a `for` loop instead. `foreach` was just more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

```
function has_dupes($array){
    $dupe = array();

    foreach($array as $val){
         if(++$dupe[$val] > 1)
             return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

could do something like this.. this would check for dupes, then u can print the uniques

Answer (score -1):

Why are you making a simple task complex .. simply

```
$b = array('a','b','c','a','b');
var_dump(customCount($b));
```

Output

```
array (size=3)
  'a' => int 2 //duplicate 
  'b' => int 2 //duplicate 
  'c' => int 1
```

Function Used

```
function customCount($array) {
    $temp = array();
    foreach ( $array as $v ) {
        isset($temp[$v]) or $temp[$v] = 0;
        $temp[$v] ++;
    }

    return $temp ;
}
```